# Como retornar uma promise de JavaScript em uma WebView no .NET MAUI?

Tags: javascript, maui

Estou utilizando uma Webview para executar uma função Javascript assíncrona, porém o .NET MAUI não aguarda a promise ser concluída e me retorna vazio. A única função de chamadas Javascript do MAUI é a função: `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync();`
Existe uma forma de retornar o valor da promise?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Para aqueles que estiverem com essa dificuldade.
Até está data o MAUI não espera uma promise ser resolvida, você pode chamar a função esperar um tempo até que ela seja resolvida e pegar o resultado com outra função.
No meu caso coloquei o resultado da promise em um input e com outra função peguei o mesmo